# How i can send get request by using id as a query string route parameter from angular to Asp.Net Rest Api

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular14

I'm trying to send get request from angular to rest api by using id as a query string route parameter.In controller class i have a action method where i want to receive id as a query string route parameter but i don't know how i have to send request from angular to rest api.

**Angular service class get method**

```
 getAdvertisement(id: number): Observable<Advertisement> {
    return this.http.get<Advertisement>(`${this.baseApiUrl}/api/advertisements?id=${id}`);
  }
```

**Component class**

**here in this line "this.advertisementService.getAdvertisement(id)" i'm receiving that error "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'." **

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  advDetails: Advertisement={
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    price: '',
    description: ''
  };
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private advertisementService: AdvertisementsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params.get('id');
      this.advertisementService.getAdvertisement(id).subscribe(response =>{
        // here in id i'm receiving that error
        this.advDetails = response;
      });
      
      // if(id != null){
      // }
    });
  }

}
```

**Controller class action method**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAdvertisements()
        {
            try
            {
                string temp = Request.Query["id"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temp))
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
                    if (id > 0)
                    {
                        AdvertisementModel adv = new AdvertisementsHandler().GetAdv(id).ToModel();
                        return Ok(adv);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex); //Internal server error;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'." **

is caused by passing string to method that requires number.

you can fix it very easily by modifying this method to accept string instead of number

```
    getAdvertisement(id: string): Observable<Advertisement> {
    return this.http.get<Advertisement>(`${this.baseApiUrl}/api/advertisements?id=${id}`);
  }
```

The problem is that if for some reason this string will not be a number you will get exception from backend.

Other thing that you can do is to cast it to number in angular:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id = parseInt(params.get('id'));
      if (!id) {
        //handle case when id is not an integer number
        return;
      }

      this.advertisementService.getAdvertisement(id).subscribe(response =>{
        // here in id i'm receiving that error
        this.advDetails = response;
      });
      
      // if(id != null){
      // }
    });
  }
```